# Firebase Google Sign-in nothing happen, but EmailPassword works, no error log cat

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, firebase, google-signin

I'm using this project : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

The exact same code, the only change I've made is applicationID in build.gradle so it match my app id in firebase..I'd also copy the SHA1 and download do google json file into app folder, NO ERROR in log cat, I've trying to sign up using Email and password and it works! I receive the email to verify my email.
However, when I try to use Google Sign-in (using another email/GMail), the choices appear, I choose my gmail account, and then NOTHING happen.. no ERROR log.. I confused :(
I'd also try to add new account and the result are the same..
please help :( Thank you

btw, I already enable Google Sign-In Method in firebase in the first step..

Comment: May I ask: 1) did you complete the [Add Firebase to your Android Project part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and add your own google-services.json to your project? 2) On your Fierbase Console, did you enable authentication via Google?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. I said that

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the app to your phone from another computer than the one you added the SHA1 from? As this will stop OAUTH from working - like you're describing. If this is a separate computer, then add generate the signing report and add the SHA1 to your application using the Firebase console.

Comment: I don't get it. I install it to my phone from my PC where I create the certificate to get SHA1. Not from other computer. What do u mean from different comp? Thank you

Comment: he meant that SHA1 for each computer is different. so if you are on debug mode maybe your app will work on one computer but not on another.

Comment: Hmm, I use only one computer, and it (google sign in) doesn't work at all in emulator in my pc or my Smartphone.